# App freezes when invoking Amplify.DataStore.save()

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-amplify

I'm using Kotlin and AWS Amplify to make a simple mobile app. I'll begin by showing what I have setup. My schema.graphql:

```
type OfferGQL @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  description: String!
  address: String!
  price: Float!
}
```

My AWS plugins are setup like this:

```
    Amplify.addPlugin(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
    Amplify.addPlugin(AWSS3StoragePlugin())
    Amplify.addPlugin(AWSDataStorePlugin())
    Amplify.configure(applicationContext)
```

This is how I try to save my data to the DataStore:

```
// Create a new offer object
val newOffer = OfferGQL.builder()
    .name(textFieldOfferName.text.toString())
    .description(textFieldOfferDescription.text.toString())
    .address(textFieldOfferAddress.text.toString())
    .price(textFieldOfferPrice.text.toString().toFloat())
    .build()

// Put it in the DataStore
Amplify.DataStore.save(newOffer,
    {result ->
        runOnUiThread{Toast.makeText(this,"Offer added successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}
    },
    {error ->
        println(error.message)
        println(error.localizedMessage)
        println(error.cause)
        println(error.recoverySuggestion)
    })
```

The problem is that when I invoke Amplify.DataStore.save() the entire app freezes. I followed the documentation to configure everything so I don't really now why this is happening.

Comment: Which versions are you using? We had this specific problem in 1.1.0, and you should be able to fix it by upgrading to 1.1.1. The difference between the two versions is specifically a fix for this issue. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/pull/653

Comment: For cross-reference, @KapitaiN also created an issue for this in the Amplify Android GitHub repository, here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues/706

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a full reinstall of the app on my phone the function finally works.